# Using concat to put together a simple string, a subquery, and another simple string

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, concatenation

I am needing to use concat to create custom sql statements.

I'm trying to use

```
update setuptable set image_loc = CONCAT('/file/to/image/', (select UID from table1), 'nam.jpg')
```

The goal is to update the image_loc in setuptable to "/file/to/image/UIDnam.jpg"

I'm getting Syntax errors and "Expected End of Statement".

How can i tie a simple string, a subquery, and another simple string together to update  a field?

Comment: Your query should work if the subquery returns 0 or 1 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work. If any one has any tips of improvement, I'm up to learn!
*I can't use variables

```
update setuptable set image_loc = CONCAT('/file/to/image/', (select UID from table1)+, 'nam.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found slightly better following structure :

```
update setuptable 
set image_loc = CONCAT('/file/to/image/', t1.UID, 'nam.jpg')
from table1 t1
```

I don't have mysql server at hand for the moment, so I have not tested.

Comment: Is putting 'from table1 t1' at the end creating some sort of variable? I get a syntax error trying that.

Comment: It creates a join, not variable. What syntax error have you got ?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Error In Expression (9).
 << Syntax Error >>

Comment: Can you start `mysql` and run the `update` statement ?